# Can Pybossa be used as a micro tasking / contest platform?

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, reddit, pybossa

I was wondering if it was possible to use Pybossa as a micro tasking / contest platform?
I am looking for something where I can register users, and get them to complete micro tasks such as twitter upvotes, retweeting, commenting, as well as reddit, youtube and things like that?
One platform currently is vyper.io which does a similar thing. 
I was looking for an open source alternative that I can customise myself.

Can Pybossa do this? or if not, do you know if something else similar can?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with PYBOSSA. Basically, PYBOSSA allows you to design any type of data, due to its JSON data storage facilities. In there you can put images, audios, webmaps, anything that can be rendered on the web and then ask users to complete those micro-tasks.

PYBOSSA has webooks APIs, allowing you to react in real-time to the feedback the users are sending to you. Thus, imagine that you are asking to upvote a given image. Say you want at least 10 people to participate in it. When the tenth person sends his/her feedback, PYBOSSA will notify you via the webhooks solution that this task has been completed. Then, another micro-service could get it, do some statistics analysis and say, hey 8 out 10 agree this is the best image. Then, you can push that info to any other service like Twitter, Facebook, etc.

I hope it helps you.

NOTE: I'm the creator of PYBOSSA.